# Send Email on Order Complete to the custom email fields

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

following code register custom fields based on number of virtual product in cart:

```
function cart_has_virtual_product() {
    if ( ! is_a( WC()->cart, 'WC_Cart' ) ) {
        return 0;
    }

    $virtual_product_count = 0;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        if ( $product->is_virtual() ) {
            $virtual_product_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
    }
    return $virtual_product_count;
}


add_filter('woocommerce_form_field', 'addHeadingsInBetweenFormFields', 10, 4);

function addHeadingsInBetweenFormFields($field, $key, $args, $value = null) {

  if (is_checkout() & $key === 'order_jmeno_ucastnika') {
    $a = '<h3>Údaje o účastníkovi kurzu</h3>';
    return $a . $field;
  }
  return $field;

}



function add_custom_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $virtual_product_count = cart_has_virtual_product();

    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $virtual_product_count; $i++ ) {
        $fields['order']['order_jmeno_ucastnika' . $i] = array(
            'label'     => 'Jméno účastníka ' . $i,
            'placeholder'   => 'Jméno Příjmení',
            'required'  => true,
            'class'     => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
            'clear'     => true
        );

        $fields['order']['order_email_ucastnika' . $i] = array(
            'type'      => 'email',
            'label'     => 'E-mail účastníka ' . $i,
            'placeholder'   => '',
            'required'  => true,
            'class'     => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
            'clear'     => true
        );

       $fields['order']['order_title' . $i] = array(
            'label'     => 'Titul/y' . $i,
            'placeholder'   => 'Titul/y',
            'required'  => false,
            'class'     => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
            'clear'     => true
        );

$fields['order']['order_birthdate' . $i] = array(
    'type'      => 'date',
    'label'     => 'Datum narození' . $i,
    'placeholder'   => 'DD.MM.RRRR',
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
    'clear'     => true
);
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

and then this fields go to the order details in administration:

```
function save_custom_checkout_fields( $order_id, $posted_data ) {
    $virtual_product_count = cart_has_virtual_product();

    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $virtual_product_count; $i++ ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['order_jmeno_ucastnika' . $i] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $order_id, 'order_jmeno_ucastnika' . $i, sanitize_text_field( $_POST['order_jmeno_ucastnika' . $i] ) );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['order_email_ucastnika' . $i] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $order_id, 'order_email_ucastnika' . $i, sanitize_email( $_POST['order_email_ucastnika' . $i] ) );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['order_title' . $i] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $order_id, 'order_title' . $i, sanitize_text_field( $_POST['order_title' . $i] ) );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['order_birthdate' . $i] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $order_id, 'order_birthdate' . $i, sanitize_text_field( $_POST['order_birthdate' . $i] ) );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_custom_checkout_fields', 10, 2 );
```

And then when is order completed, we should send email to all recipients what are in fields 'order_email_ucastnika. And here is the issue. When i had recipient set to billing email, it was working fine. But now emails are not sent.

```
function send_zoom_link_on_order_complete( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $virtual_product_count = cart_has_virtual_product();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $zoom_link = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'zoom_link', true );
        $custom_info = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_info', true );

        if ( $zoom_link ) {
            for ( $i = 1; $i <= $virtual_product_count; $i++ ) {
                $to = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'order_email_ucastnika' . $i, true );
                $subject = 'my subject ' . $item->get_name();
                $message = 'link: ' . $zoom_link . $custom_info;

                // add headers
                $headers = array(
                    'From: mysite.com <orders@mysite.com>',
                    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'
                );

                wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
        }
    }
}
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'send_zoom_link_on_order_complete');
```

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: So, to confirm, only the line ```$to = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'order_email_ucastnika' . $i, true );``` has been changed, and nothing else.  And it stopped working?
Have you tried to log and see exactly what is stored in `$to` after this line is executed? Does it show up as a valid email?

Comment: no, there was many changes in code for edit billing email to multiple fields "order_email_ucastnika". How can i get log from $to?

Comment: You can use `print_r($to);` to print the values in the console (STDOUT must be redirected to some file). And if the whole code is changed to do this, the problem might be somewhere else also. `When i had recipient set to billing email, it was working fine. But now emails are not sent` - this might not be just related to email, but may be other logic too.

Comment: print_r($to) under  wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );?

Comment: Just after `$to = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'order_email_ucastnika' . $i, true );` to see whether it is retrieved as a valid email address or not.  There is no change in `wp_mail` function, right?  So if it is called with proper data, it should function just like earlier?

Comment: Yes it should. When i do test order, i have to in administration mark it as completed and page is refreshed. But how can i see the output from print_r($to); in console?

Comment: If the execution is as part of an HTTP request, the `print_r` output will directly show up on the browser.  You can do `print_r($to); exit();` to stop execution and see what is printed on the web-page.

Comment: I don't know, page was refreshed and i didn't see any output of $to value in browser. Also i tried add under $to wp_die(); and WP not died. Seems it can be related with if ( $zoom_link ) { or something in function.

Comment: The issue must in this loop:  for `( $i = 1; $i <= $virtual_product_count; $i++ )` when i comment this line, wp_die() being executed otherwise everything under this line was not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the issue. The problem was in variable `$virtual_product_count = cart_has_virtual_product();` which got data from the cart instead of the order.

The correct code looks like this:

```
function send_zoom_link_on_order_complete( $order_id ) {
    function order_has_virtual_product( $order_id ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        if ( ! $order ) {
            return 0;
        }

        $virtual_product_count = 0;

        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            $product = $item->get_product();
            if ( $product->is_virtual() ) {
                $virtual_product_count += $item->get_quantity();
            }
        }
        return $virtual_product_count;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $virtual_product_count = order_has_virtual_product( $order_id );

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $zoom_link = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'zoom_link', true );
        $custom_info = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_info', true );

        if ( $zoom_link ) {
            for ( $i = 1; $i <= $virtual_product_count; $i++ ) {
                $to = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'order_email_ucastnika' . $i, true );
                $subject = 'my subject ' . $item->get_name();
                $message = 'link: ' . $zoom_link . $custom_info;

                // add headers
                $headers = array(
                    'From: mysite.com <orders@mysite.com>',
                    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'
                );

                wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'send_zoom_link_on_order_complete' );
```